# Finding Remote Points in 2D

Tags: c#, 2d, point

I have a set of points on the infinite (well, double precision) 2D plane.

Given the convex hull for this set, how can find some points on the *inside* of the convex hull that are relatively far away from all the points in the input set?

In the image below, the black points are part of the original set and the hatched area represents the space taken up by all the points if we "grow" them with radius R.

The orange points are examples of what I'd like to get. It doesn't really matter where exactly they are, as long as they are relatively far away from all the black points.

[Furthest Point Search http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/point_far_search.png](http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/point_far_search.png)

---

Update: Using a delaunay algorithm to find large empty triangles seems to be a great approach for this:
[Delaunay Solution http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/DelaunaySolutionToInternalFurthestPoints.png](http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/DelaunaySolutionToInternalFurthestPoints.png)

Comment: Do you have equations describing this surface? It sounds like you are asking for a 3D solution since the orange dots are on the inside.

Comment: Is this an accurate rephrasing of the question? "I have a set of points; I wish to order them, descending, by distance to the nearest other point in the set, and then discarding from my ordering any points on the convex hull".  You could then take the top n items from that list.

Comment: I think the orange points are possible points he wants to determine, not points that are in the set.

Comment: @Eric, no. I have a set of points and I want to find new points, starting with the one that is furthest away from everything else.

Comment: Ah, got it. Do a web search on "Voronoi diagram". I think that might help you. I'd be willing to bet that there's a relationshjp between the largest voronoi region and its edges to the set you wish to determine.

Comment: @Eric, Voronoi diagrams and Delaunay triangulations are duals of each other, so the largest triangle in a delaunay mesh would probably yield the same result. Unfortunately the code I wrote for delaunay and voronoi are in a different project (VB.NET D'oh!), so it will take me some time to translate it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of a problem that may be solved using [KD-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)... there are some good notes in Numerical Recipes 3rd Addition.

If you are trying to find point locations that are relatively isolated... maybe the center of the largest quad elements would be a good candidate.

The complexity would be O(n log^2 n) for creating the KD-Tree... and creating a sorted list of quad sizes would be O(n Log n).  Seems reasonable for even a large number of points (of course, depending on your requirements).

Comment: Interesting. I'll pursue this, it definitely sounds promising. Either find empty rectangles in Kd or Quad trees, or perhaps the centers of large triangles in a Delaunay triangulation.

Comment: one other thing may be that area could be misleading... you could have a tall skinny box, so it would actually be close to a point.  Probably a better metric would be the quad's smallest edge length, and find the quads that maximize this metric.

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive algorithm:

1. Get the list of points within the convex shape.
2. Of those, find the minimum distance to any other point.
3. Rank all points by their respective R values
4. Select the top x points.

For (2), thinking of this as a radius search still means you end up calculating the distance from each point to each other point, because finding out whether a point lies within a given radius of another point is the same thing as finding the distance between the points.

To optimize the search, you can divide the space into a grid, and assign each point to a grid location. Then, your search for (2) above would first check within the same square *and* the surrounding 8 squares. If the minimum distance to another point is within the *same* square, return that value. If it is from one of the 8 and the distance is such that a point outside the 9 could be closer, you have to then check the next outline of grid locations outside those 9 for any closer than those found within the 9. Rinse/repeat.

Comment: This only works if the "orange" points are known in advance - I think he's trying to find/generate points that aren't close to the others.

Comment: I can find nearest points pretty quickly with a QuadTree structure, that code I already have standing by. The problem is that the number of points inside the convex hull is enormous. To get the kind of accuracy I need would require millions upon millions of searches. The image shows a rather nice distribution, but sometimes the points are extremely clustered into far away galaxies.

I need this to be really fast since it's called within a GUI and I need to keep the refresh rate over 30 frames per second. 

I appreciate the answer, but this won't do.

Comment: @Reed: my algorithm was comparing *every* point to *every other* point, so it would automatically identify which ones (based on some "TOP x"-style threshold should be considered "orange."